# Making a button click when pressing enter instead of clicking the control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to make a button called btnSubmit submit my customer's information if they hit enter on the keyboard. I know in VS2012 if I'm coding strictly C#, I can change the properties very easily and set up a button to be activated when enter is pressed.

Because I am coding in .net with C#, I do not have that option for my control. Any advice with coding? Can't find anything.

I am working with a web form.

Comment: Is it WPF or WinForm?

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do the trick.

Don't attempt to trigger a button click. Essentially what you should do is refactor your code so that the event handlers are separated from the actual implementation. e.g.

```
void Form_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        CheckAnswer();
    }
}

public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckAnswer();
}

private void CheckAnswer()
{
    // do your stuffs on button click 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `UseSubmitBehavior` property for your button control and set it to `TRUE` like

```
UseSubmitBehavior="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a `Panel` and set its `DefaultButton` property with the name of the submit button. Every time you hit 'enter' in any `TextBox` inside the panel, it will call button's `OnClick` event. Like this:

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" DefaultButton="Button1">

    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click"  />

</asp:Panel>
```